# How to set up associations in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, models

I'm building a sample app for practice and am having trouble determining the best way to organize my models and associations. So let's just say I have 3 models:

1. Schools
2. Classes
3. Students

I want:

- schools to have many classes
- classes to have many students
- classes to belong to a school
- students to be enrolled in many classes in many different schools

The associations are making me dizzy, I'm not sure which ones to use. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renamed `class` to `course`, as the class name `Class` is already taken.  A join class such as `enrollments` would handle your many to many course <=> student relationship.

```
class School
  has_many :courses
end

class Course
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, :through => :enrollments
end

class Student
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments
end

class Enrollment
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your models should looks like this:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classes
  has_many :students, :through => :classes
end

class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :classes
end
```

Make sure your Student and Class tables have `class_id` and `school_id` columns respectively.

Also, Class is a [reserved word in Rails](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords), so it might cause problems (you might have to use a different name)

Comment: If I wanted to list on the student profile what schools they are a part of, should I call student.class.school? Or should I add to the student model has_many :schools, :through => :classes ?

Comment: Also I want students to belong to many classes so would your solution not work?

Comment: Apologies should have been has_and_belongs_to_many. Answer updated. With `:through` you can just call `@school.students`

Comment: Don't think this works guys unless I'm just dead wrong. I said that I wanted students to be a part of multiple schools as well. How would that be added? But remember they belong to these school via the classes, would it be a has_many :through?

Comment: Ok so now I have three different answers that all seem to make sense. Which one is the most efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Though on first blush it would seem students should belong directly to class, class isn't really a true "has_and_belongs_to_many" replacement. For that I would use "enrollment". (Note with rails 3.1 you can now do nested :through calls.)

Here's a slightly more advanced implementation than the previous commenter's:

```
class School << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :academic_classes
  has_many :enrollments, :through => :academic_classes
  has_many :students, :through => :enrollments, :uniq => true
end

class AcademicClass << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :enrollments
end

class Enrollment << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :academic_class
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :academic_classes, :through => :enrollments
  has_many :schools, :through => :academic_classes, :uniq => true
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. If I wanted to list the schools that each student is in how would I call it using this solution?

Comment: I updated the example to show you how you could do something like:

@student.schools